# Wordpress child theme not applying style via JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am enqueueing script which applies the class "first-half" to the first half of all the li elements under ul#menu-main. The class is not showing.

What I have:

In "themes/responsive-child/js/menu.js":

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var menuItems = $("ul#menu-main li");

    menuItems = menuItems.slice(0, Math.floor(menuItems.length/2)).addClass("first-half");

});
```

In "functions.php" of child theme:

```
add_action('init', 'menuscript_init');

function menuscript_init() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'menuscript_init', '<?php get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/js/menu.js'); 
}
```

Please point out what I did wrong

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<?php get_stylesheet_directory() ?>
```

to

```
<?php get_template_directory() ?>
```

Comment: does not fix the problem - get_stylesheet_directory() returns child theme directory path, get_template_directory() returns parent theme

Comment: do you have an additional functions.php file in your child theme? Because otherwise, this should point to the correct file. Just take a look to page source of the site and check if js/menu.js is loading. If yes, then problem is your code (which, at first sight, looks OK to me). If not, then the problem is your path. So, unless you have an additional functions file, you should point at the core's functions

Comment: Thanks, I checked page source, and it was referencing the file incorrectly - get_stylesheet_directory_uri(), not get_stylesheet_directory() --- now the file is there but the js is still not working

Comment: Problem is the jquery code, which I am not versed in.. Any help possible?

Comment: Look my answer...you have to include the array('jquery') to tell wordpress that you're going to use jquery

Answer (score 0):

change jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var menuItems = jQuery("ul#menu-main li");

    menuItems = menuItems.slice(0, Math.floor(menuItems.length/2)).addClass("first-half");

});
```

and change wp_enqueue_script() to :

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'menuscript_init', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/menu.js', array('jquery'));
```

hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you.
Your problem is in functions.php, you have to have something like:

```
wp_register_script( 'editing_unit_javascript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/menu.js', array('jquery','bootstrap'));
wp_enqueue_script( 'menu_javascript' );
```

EDIT: You can remove 'bootstrap' from array, because you are going to use jquery in your javascript file